# How can I vectorize the apply + filter operation on pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

Imagine that I have a Dataframe and the columns are `[A,B,C]`. There are some different values for each of these columns. And I want to produce one more column `D` which can be received with the following function:

```
def produce_column(i):
    # Extract current row by index
    raw = df.loc[i]

    # Extract previous 3 values for the same sub-df which are before i
    df_same = df[
        (df['A'] == raw.A)
        & (df['B'] == raw.B)
    ].loc[:i].tail(3)

    # Check that we have enough values
    if df_same.shape[0] != 3:
        return False

    # Doesn't matter which function is in use, I just need to apply it on the column / columns
    diffs = df_same['C'].map(lambda x: x <= 10 and x > 0)

    return all(diffs)

df['D'] = df.index.map(lambda x: produce_column(x))
```

So on each step, I need to get the Dataframe, which have the same set of properties as a row and perform some operations on columns of this Dataframe. I have a few hundred thousands of rows, so this code takes a lot of time to be executed. I think that a good idea is to vectorize the operation, but I don't know how to do that. Maybe there's another way to perform this?

Thanks in advance!

**UPD** Here's an example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)], columns=['A','B','C'])

    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9


df['D'] = df.index.map(lambda x: produce_column(x))
    A   B   C   D
0   1   2   3   True
1   4   5   6   True
2   7   8   9   False
```

Comment: Can you please post some example input and expected output data?

Comment: @NilsWerner sure, check the update, please

Comment: What's the value of `N`? For all values I tried I get a different output

Comment: @NilsWerner sorry, my bad. Let's imagine that `N = 3`.